# What is the correct GraphQL syntax for Select *?

Tags: graphql

How would I write a select all query in GraphSQ. Is Select * possible with introspection on?

Also did the syntax change as I see T. required in some versions?

```
query: """select * from "categories" where label = $1"""
```

or

```
query: """select T.* from "categories" T where T."label" = $1"""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query all the GraphQL type fields without writing a long query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199982/how-to-query-all-the-graphql-type-fields-without-writing-a-long-query)

Comment: "Is Select * possible?"  By design it is not.  Your GraphQL query should select the specific fields that your application is going to use from the object types.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that article but in a YouTube tutorial I saw the instructor use "Select *" and it worked. Was this possible in the past then deprecated by StepZen or GraphQL? @DavidMaze